# background-image not working when used in external stylesheet,works perfectly fine when used <style> tag in html

Tags: background-image

HTML CODE:
(Image is present in the right directory)

```
    <html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">     
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Sample Header</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <article>
            <h2>Sample Header 2</h2>
            <p>Sample Paragraph 1</p>        
            <p>Sample Paragraph 2</p>
        </article>
    </main>
</body>
```

CSS CODE:

```
html{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background-image: url('images/pattern.png');
background-color: burlywood;
}
body {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: white;
position: relative;
}
header {
height: 150px;
}
h1 {
font-size: 50px;
line-height: 140px;
margin: 0 0 0 32.5px;
}
main {
background: #ccc;
}
article {
padding: 20px;
}
h2 {
margin-top: 0;
}
p {
line-height: 2;
}
```

background-image does not work in the above form,but when the same css-code is included in style tag,background-image works perfectly fine,why not in external stylesheet?

Comment: You probably have a syntax issue or your css file is not loaded. Please provide both versions. Beware of the path for the image file. If you load a CSS file from a child folder you have to adapt you relative path.

Comment: open network tool on your browser to see if there is any failed requests (you should reload to see all requests), it could be the style sheet itself or the image, if there is any failure that means path to that file is not correct

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a path issue for the `background-image: url(...)`. I can't reproduce at the moment because of lacking information but please be aware of your folder structure. When you use `<style>` for CSS the starting point for the relative path is your root folder (or where the HTML is located).

In case of the `style.css` the starting point is the folder `styles`. So mind that in that case the path might have to change. You can use the [Firefox developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) or [Chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css) to modify your path on the fly. This way you can easily find out yourself where the issue with the path originates or if the `background-image` rule was applied properly on your element.

**Updated:** added links to developer tools (Mozilla, Google)

Comment: The problem was in background-image path.it got solved by adding '..' before the path. Thank You for the help- Thex, Vahid

Comment: @pritam_sable glad you found the culprit, you are welcome!